Nanopi / Debian - Disabling Auto Login Breaks Sound
I have the NanoPi R6C.  The vendor, FriendlyElec, provide an image of Debian 11.  I flash this to the eMMC.  Out of the box, sound works through the USB headphones (though not through HDMI).
The image uses xfce and LightDM and the latter has been configured to enable auto login for a preconfigured user pi.  If I disable auto login, then I no longer get sound through the headphones.  Any idea what could cause this?
If I start up the device with auto login enabled, the log file includes:
May 27 09:16:00 NanoPi-R6C kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
May 27 09:16:02 NanoPi-R6C dbus-daemon[519]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.41' (uid=1000 pid=800 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo")
May 27 09:16:02 NanoPi-R6C pulseaudio[800]: [0;1;31m[0;1;39m[0;1;31mmodule-rescue-stream is obsolete and should no longer be loaded. Please remove it from your configuration.[0m
May 27 09:16:02 NanoPi-R6C pulseaudio[800]: [0;1;38;5;185m[0;1;39m[0;1;38;5;185mUnable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11[0m
May 27 09:16:02 NanoPi-R6C pulseaudio[800]: [0;1;38;5;185m[0;1;39m[0;1;38;5;185mUnable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11[0m

And sound works okay.  If I start the device up with auto login disabled, the log file includes all of the above, plus the following:
May 27 09:20:38 NanoPi-R6C pulseaudio[925]: [0;1;31m[0;1;39m[0;1;31mbind(): Address already in use[0m
May 27 09:20:38 NanoPi-R6C pulseaudio[925]: [0;1;31m[0;1;39m[0;1;31mFailed to load module "module-native-protocol-unix" (argument: "auth-anonymous=1 socket=/tmp/pulse-socket"): initialization failed.[0m
May 27 09:20:38 NanoPi-R6C pulseaudio[925]: [0;1;31m[0;1;39m[0;1;31mmodule-rescue-stream is obsolete and should no longer be loaded. Please remove it from your configuration.[0m
May 27 09:20:38 NanoPi-R6C pulseaudio[925]: [0;1;38;5;185m[0;1;39m[0;1;38;5;185mUnable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11[0m
May 27 09:20:38 NanoPi-R6C pulseaudio[925]: [0;1;38;5;185m[0;1;39m[0;1;38;5;185mUnable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11[0m
May 27 09:20:40 NanoPi-R6C pulseaudio[796]: No protocol specified
May 27 09:20:40 NanoPi-R6C pulseaudio[796]: [0;1;31m[0;1;39m[0;1;31mXOpenDisplay() failed[0m
May 27 09:20:40 NanoPi-R6C pulseaudio[796]: [0;1;31m[0;1;39m[0;1;31mFailed to load module "module-x11-publish" (argument: "display=:0.0 xauthority=/home/pi/.Xauthority"): initialization failed.[0m
May 27 09:20:50 NanoPi-R6C systemd[782]: pulseaudio.service: Succeeded.
May 27 09:20:50 NanoPi-R6C systemd[782]: pulseaudio.socket: Succeeded.

And the sound does not work.  In that case if I do systemctl --user restart pulseaudio then the sound starts working again.
I have spent many hours digging for the cause of the error, to no avail.  I would be grateful for any assistance.
